# My phone buzzes (twice) but no notification

Tags: notifications, lineageos, vibration, push-notifications

Since maybe a week I have this weird situation where my phone buzzes twice every so often, but there is no notification. It is really annoying.

I saw some search results suggesting that this is a notification reminder in Accessibility -> but I cant find such an option in that section of the settings.

Others suggested that this might be apps that are blocked from notifications that are trying to create push notifications but I was able to confirm(reasonably) this isnt the case by unblocking all of them.

Recently I updated my phone, and installed Any.do. I verified that it isnt Any.do either.

I am using One Plus One, with Lineage 14.1, and when I say I updated my phone it is to a newer nightly of 14.1.

Comment: If there is a way to check which app triggered the last vibration API call, that would be perfect..

Comment: My phone kinda restarts(probably crashes) every so often (atleast once a day) So restarting to see if it fixes it doesnt work

Comment: I installed https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evanhe.nhfree&amp;hl=en but I dont know how to activate "go to system Notification Access settings and check Notification History"

Comment: I have that app and was checking it . It didn't seem to record any system buzz instances. I don't have your OS so can't tell how to activate

Comment: For posterity, I figured out the Notification access thing. When opening the app and it shows the popup, can just click the line to go to the settings. Else it is Settings -> Apps -> Settings -> Special Access -> Notification Access

Comment: I'm having the same problem on Lineage 14 on my Nexus 5X, as well as most notifications being heavily delayed (maybe unrelated).  I don't have AccuBattery installed.

Comment: Lineage as well..

Answer (score 1):

After using https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evanhe.nhfree&hl=en I discovered that all of my ghost vibrates were due to Accu Battery. Some search results had pointed to that but I did not consider because i hadnt made any changes to it recently, but the problem had only started recently.

Comment: I disabled AccuBattery notification but the ghost vibrations are still happening.. now with no record in the history app